# ¿Obtener una palabra dentro una cadena de texto?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

necesito ayuda, realizp una consulta a mi bd que devuelve eso:
dormitorios1,baños1,amoblado,garaje1,terraza,
Necesitaria algunan forma para guardar cada valor en una variable diferente(vb.net).
Gracias

Comment: Investiga sobre `Split()`

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no está clara, ¿qués has intentado?, ¿cómo obtienes los datos?. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos